# Is I2C write/read wearout possible for the MLX90393

Tags: sensor, i2c

I am using an MLX90393 on a custom-built and ordered PCB (there are no other components) in I2C-Mode.

[Please find the datasheet here.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwji24iJ56z4AhUbgv0HHRUTDAoQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.melexis.com%2F-%2Fmedia%2Ffiles%2Fdocuments%2Fdatasheets%2Fmlx90393-datasheet-melexis.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3P4--qpEqCBqITX7BAEa0i)

I am using the smbus library to read from the sensor around each second. [The code is built on top of this example](http://www.pibits.net/code/raspberry-pi-and-mlx90393-magnetic-field-sensor-example.php), which works fine.

In addition to the MLX90393, I am using a [TCA9548 Multiplexer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiAgt2956z4AhXXi_0HHZHrC70QFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Ftca9548a&usg=AOvVaw0QWduF8uMcYJg7xvHj6Vry) from Ti to readout 8xMLX90393.

[Please see the dump for the minimum code example here.](https://www.codedump.xyz/perl/YqhtOlkSaC3KI-6B)

Following write/read ‘actions’ on the MLX90393 work fine:
data = bus.read_byte(mlx90393_address)

```
> # MLX90393 address, 0x0C(12)
> # Select write register command, 0x60(96)
> # AH = 0x02, AL = 0xB4, RES for magnetic measurement = 0, Address register (0x02 << 2) config = [0x02, 0xB4, 0x08]
> bus.write_i2c_block_data(mlx90393_address, 0x60, config)
> # Read data back, 1 byte
> # Status byte data = bus.read_byte(mlx90393_address)
> 
> # MLX90393 address, 0x0C(12)
> # Start single meaurement mode, X, Y, Z-Axis enabled bus.write_byte(mlx90393_address, 0x3E)
```

However, the data cannot be retrieved afterwards using:

```
data = bus.read_byte(mlx90393_address)
```

There is clearly a difference if a 'defect' MLX90393 sensor is attached compared to no sensor attached. For the defect sensor attached, the relevant data registers can not be read anymore.

Could there be a wear-out effect by jamming the data register each 1sec, 24/7? What other error sources come to your mind? I have 40 of those sensors. In the first week, 2 died, now I am at 7/40.

EDIT after @CL question on how noisy the environment is:

The 8 MLX90393 channels are muxed over a TCA9548
[image]

The MLx90393 is placed on a small around 10x10mm PCB, please see below:
[image]

10µF and 0.1µF decoupling caps are selected according ot the data sheet, 3.3V power is provided over the RPI PIN, which I measured to be stable.

In addition, this [I2C range extender is used](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4756) because I use cable sizes of around 1m, which caused some troubles.

EDIT2 - 15th June 22:

I have compared MLX90393 probes that work with the defect ones, the pullup resistances for the defect probes reach oc:
[image]

This is unexpected since I placed 10k pullups on the board and 6/6 working probes show that behavior, also 6/6 working probes show 20k resistance between SCL/SDA.

I have sealed the MLX90393 in 5min epoxy. Can it be that the epoxy attacks the PCB / detaches components?

Comment: What does it mean when you say data can't be retrieved? Isn't that just reading the status byte after sending command to start single conversion? Chip does not respond? Returns weird values?

Comment: You are using the WR command, which says it impacts only the volatile memory. RAM will not wear out quickly (if at all). Is your code really producing a Restart condition on the I²C bus? Some chips can be pretty picky about the timing on the I²C bus.

Comment: Probably overvoltage. Show the schematic, the boards, and tell us how noisy the environment is.

Comment: @Arsenal how can I ensure a proper restart condition in the minimum code dump example that I provided? If the sensors will work there 'again' then this would be the fix.

Comment: @MarcoBobinger sorry, I can't tell you that, I'm not familiar with the smbus library - in fact I'm not familiar with Raspberry Pis at all. I'd use a logic analyzer to check what is going on on the bus.

Comment: @Justme chip doesn't return values but fails to return data after second write/read attempt, i.e. bus.write_byte(mlx90393_address, 0x3E) and data = bus.read_byte(mlx90393_address). For the first write/read, i.e. bus.write_i2c_block_data(mlx90393_address, 0x60, config), whereas config = [0x00, 0x5c, 0x00] it returns the byte 72 for data = bus.read_byte(mlx90393_address). Please see the minimum code example, the code I just quoted is in there.

Comment: @MarcoBobinger And now there suddenly is 1 meter cables and I2C range extender? Please draw the whole I2C bus system and edit the info to your question. We can't guess where the range extender is and how many there are and what links are 1 meter and what cable you used. All pull-up resistor values an their location as well. With proper design I2C should go for several meters with no special measures, but it requires proper design.

Comment: The LTC4311 is a constant-current source and probably not a problem. But long cables can lead to problems; please check VCC/SDA/SCL at the sensors with an oscilloscope.

Comment: @Justme I will provide a schematic of the system asap. The defect can be nailed down to the sensor probe (please see my latest edit). I sealed the MLX90393 probe with 5minute epoxy to be able to put it in water continuously. I have measured the resistances between VCC, GND, SCL and SDA and saw that the pullup connectors are somehow broken. The PCBs were assembled from a company so this is unexpected.